# Web API versioning URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm having a bit of a problem trying to version my Web API:

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[ApiVersion("2.0")]
[System.Web.Http.Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/monitors")]
[ControllerName("Monitors")]
public sealed class MonitorsController : ApiController
{
   /* 
     /monitors/get?heartbeat=foo
   */
   [System.Web.Http.Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/monitors/get")]
   [MapToApiVersion("1.0")]
   public JsonResult GetHeartbeatStatusV1(string heartbeat)
   {
      var x = new JsonResult {Data = "heartbeat v1"};
      return x;
   }
   [System.Web.Http.Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/monitors/get")]
   [MapToApiVersion("2.0")]
   public JsonResult GetHeartbeatStatusV2(string heartbeat)
   {
      var x = new JsonResult { Data = "heartbeat v1" };
      return x;
   }
   /* 
      /monitors/get?alert=foo 
   */
   [System.Web.Http.Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/monitors/get")]
   [MapToApiVersion("2.0")]
   public JsonResult GetAlertStatus(string alert)
   {
      var x = new JsonResult {Data = "alerts"};
      return x;
   }
   /* 
      /monitors/get?oDataQuery=foo 
   */
   [System.Web.Http.Route("monitors/get")]
   public JsonResult GetODataQuery(string oDataQuery)
   {
      var x = new JsonResult {Data = "oDataQuery"};
      return x;
   }
}
```

The above is my controller. I have a bunch of actions which I want to be able to call based on version.

The problem is I also need them all to be /get then decide on which method to call based on the parameter name, this is why I have:

```
[System.Web.Http.Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/monitors/get")]
```

I thought I could decorate the method with `[MapToApiVersion("1.0")]` and `[MapToApiVersion("2.0")]` to discriminate which method is called. **However in the exmaple posted if I call `api/v1.0/monitors/get?heartbeat=foo` I get an error about multiple actions. If I call v2.0 it says it can't find any method at all.**

?

I'd like to be able to do

`http://foo:blah/api/v1.0/monitors/get?heartbeat=foo`

`http://foo:blah/api/v2.0/monitors/get?heartbeat=foo`

`http://foo:blah/api/v2.0/monitors/get?alert=foo`

Is this possible?

EDIT

---

One thing I tried was splitting them up into 2 different controllers, in different namespaces.

```
[ApiVersion("2.0")]
[System.Web.Http.Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/monitors")]
[ControllerName("Monitors")]
public sealed class MonitorsController : ApiController
{
    /* 
        /monitors/get?heartbeat=foo
    */
    [System.Web.Http.Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/monitors/get")]
    [MapToApiVersion("2.0")]
    public JsonResult GetHeartbeatStatusV2(string heartbeat)
    {
        var x = new JsonResult {Data = "heartbeat v2"};
        return x;
    }
    /* 
        /monitors/get?alert=foo 
    */
    [System.Web.Http.Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/monitors/get")]
    public JsonResult GetAlertStatus(string alert)
    {
        var x = new JsonResult {Data = "alerts"};
        return x;
    }

}
```

This has the same error of finding multiple actions.

My WebApiConfig.cs looks like this:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
        var constraintResolver = new DefaultInlineConstraintResolver
                                 {
                                     ConstraintMap =
                                     {
                                         ["apiVersion"] = typeof(ApiVersionRouteConstraint)
                                     }
                                 };
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(constraintResolver);
        config.AddApiVersioning();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/v{version:apiVersion}/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are doing it is right but instead of using the `ApiVersion`  attribute you can make it more simple and readable 
Just let MapHttpRoute as default and you can let your controller in the same namespace and just change the name  `MonitorsControllerV2`

```
[RoutePrefix("api/V2.0/monitors")] 
public sealed class MonitorsControllerV2 : ApiController
{
    /* 
        /monitors/get?heartbeat=foo
    */

     [Route("GetHeartbeat")]
    public JsonResult GetHeartbeatStatusV2(string heartbeat)
    {
        var x = new JsonResult {Data = "heartbeat v2"};
        return x;
    }
    /* 
        /monitors/get?alert=foo 
    */
      [Route(" GetAlertStatus")]
    public JsonResult GetAlertStatus(string alert)
    {
        var x = new JsonResult {Data = "alerts"};
        return x;
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried this, when I go to `http://localhost:53713/api/v2.0/monitors/Getheartbeat?heartbeat=555` I now get an error that a version is was required but not specified.

Comment: Ok, got it working by changing `[RoutePrefix("api/V2.0/monitors")] ` to ` [RoutePrefix("api/v{version:apiVersion}/monitors")]